# Filtering data with an object filtering by all values in the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search, filter

For a search I am building I want to filter an array of objects with an object.
However I am having trouble filtering by all the values in the object. The issue is that only the first value in the object is being used to filer. You can see in my example the result should be an empty array but it is returning`{Condition: ["Blueberries", "Kiwi"], Quantity: 50, ProductName: "Fruits 50 lbs"}]` because it's only checking the first value.

```js
let formItems = [
                {Condition: ["Apples", "Bannans"], Quantity: 5000, ProductName: "Fruits 650 lbs"},
                {Condition: ["Dogs", "Cats"], Quantity: 19, ProductName: "Pets 600 lbs"},
                {Condition: ["Succulents", "Evergreen"], Quantity: 1, ProductName: "Plants 6 oz"},
                {Condition: ["Blueberries", "Kiwi"], Quantity: 50, ProductName: "Fruits 50 lbs"}]
            
                let search = {Condition: "Blu", ProductName: "Fruits 650"}
            
              const handleSearch = (searchParams) => {
        
                const formFiltered = formItems.filter((el) => {
                    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(searchParams)){
                        // do(es) the object(s) contain the search value
                        if(key === "Condition"){
                            // conditions are arrays 
                           return el[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
                        }else if(key != "Condition"){
                           return el[key].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
                        }
                    }
                 
                })
             
    
       console.log(formFiltered) 
        }
    
        handleSearch(search)
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: So the requirement is for *all* values in `search` to be present in the object in `formItems`?

Comment: Yes exactly. If the `formItem` object does not contain a match for the values included in `search` it should not be included. @Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that *every* entry of the search object matches an item being iterated over - right now, you're just checking whether the first happens to match.

But a better approach than iterating over entries would be to hard-code `.Condition` and `.ProductName` - check that those two properties in the search object match.

It would also be better to check that `.some` of the items in the Condition array have the substring you're searching for, rather than stringifying the array - otherwise, commas in the search Condition could produce false positives.

```js
const formItems = [
  {Condition: ["Apples", "Bannans"], Quantity: 5000, ProductName: "Fruits 650 lbs"},
  {Condition: ["Dogs", "Cats"], Quantity: 19, ProductName: "Pets 600 lbs"},
  {Condition: ["Succulents", "Evergreen"], Quantity: 1, ProductName: "Plants 6 oz"},
  {Condition: ["Blueberries", "Kiwi"], Quantity: 50, ProductName: "Fruits 50 lbs"}]

const search = {Condition: "Blu", ProductName: "Fruits 650"};

const keys = ['Condition', 'ProductName'];
const handleSearch = (searchParams) => {
  const formFiltered = formItems.filter(item =>
    item.Condition.some(condStr => condStr.toLowerCase().includes(searchParams.Condition.toLowerCase())
    && item.ProductName.toLowerCase().includes(searchParams.ProductName.toLowerCase())
  ));
  console.log(formFiltered)
};

handleSearch(search)
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate youre response! I understand your implementation here. But this application seems very rigid and Im having a hard time figuring how I can apply this to my use case where there will be a lot more fields that a user could search by. I will look into using `.every` and `.some` thanks again!

Comment: If there are many fields, you will need some way to distinguish how to search them. For example, for Condition, there's an array of strings - for Quantity, there's a number - for ProductName, there's a string. If the types vary that much (or more), there *will* be a decent amount of boilerplate involved. You could make a mapping of property names to the appropriate function to call for it, if you had a whole bunch of properties and wanted to make things more DRY.